# PHP dev server is returning the HTTP headers in response body

Tags: php

I am using the PHP 7.4 Dev Server with the router config. Whenever the HTML requests for static content (for example, take a stylesheet `app.css`) it gives the HTTP Header Information along with the file contents

**Expected Output**

```css
body {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:3000
Date: Sun, 15 Dec 2019 19:07:32 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 44

body {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

My router.php (aka router config file)

```php
<?php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;
} else {
    include_once __DIR__ . '/index.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: When you request a static content, it doesn't run your PHP code and the server itself return the content and the HTTP header should be in the response. Right?